# Are questions about company structure and team member role/responsibilty on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

In a scenario of 4-6 back-end developers, 3-5 front-end, and 1-3 testers would it be on topic to ask what roles/tasks belong to the team chief/leader?

Comment: No, that's not on-topic.

Comment: Not here. You can try other places, like [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but I'd check with them first. You have the association bonus so you should be able to visit the chat room their help page refers to.

Comment: Most definitely belongs on https://pm.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It's off-topic for two reasons:

- It's too subjective. There's no correct answer to this, since a team is free to divide up responsibilities as it likes.
- It's more of a management problem than a "specific" and "practical" "programming problem", at least as I interpret those terms (from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Depending upon precisely what you want to ask, your question might be on-topic on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ or https://pm.stackexchange.com/, though I'm not intimately familiar with any of those communities.